# Find $P(n+1)$ using the given information

Tags: polynomials

Suppose that $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ such that

$P(k)$ = $\frac{k}{k+1}$ for $k=0,1,2,.....n$.

Find the value of $P(n+1)$.

I have absolutely no idea to start.

Comment: You need to see this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial

Comment: Since you only need to find $P(n+1)$ and not $P(x)$ itself, I think Method of differences would be easier. Check out https://brilliant.org/wiki/method-of-differences/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Say we consider $Q(x)=(x+1)P(x)-x$ where $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$.

So we can say that $Q(x)=0$ for $x=0,1,2,\ldots ,n$, or in other words, we can say that $Q(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n+1$ with $n+1$ roots namely, $0,1,2,\ldots ,n$.

Hence we can write that $$Q(x)=c(x-0)(x-1)\ldots (x-n)$$ where $c$ is the leading co-efficient.

Therefore we have that, $$(x+1)\cdot P(x)-x=c(x-0)(x-1)\ldots (x-n)$$

For $x=-1$, we have $$(-1+1) \cdot P(-1)+1=c(-1-0)(-1-1)\ldots (-1-n)$$
Or, $$1=c\cdot(-1)^{n+1}(n+1)!$$
Or, $$c=\frac{1}{(-1)^{n+1}(n+1)!}$$

So we have that $$(x+1) \cdot P(x)-x=\frac{1}{(-1)^{n+1}(n+1)!}\cdot (x-0)(x-1)\ldots (x-n)$$

Hence for $x=n+1$, we get $$(n+1+1)\cdot (n+1)-(n+1)=\frac{1}{(-1)^{n+1}(n+1)!}\cdot (n+1-0)(n+1-1)\ldots (n+1-n)$$
Or, $$(n+2)\cdot P(n+1)-(n+1)=\frac{(-1)^2}{(-1)^{n+1}(n+1)!}\cdot (n+1)!$$
Or, $$\color{red}{P(n+1)=\frac{(-1)^{1-n}}{(n+2)}+\frac{n+1}{n+2}}$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: What is k in your first line?  i don't follow this.

Comment: @user254665 It was a mistake. I have corrected it. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Very neat. Once we have c it's essentially done.

Answer (score 1):

We have $n + 1$ points on a polynomial of degree $n$. Hence, you can simply assume your polynomial to be $P(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i x^i$, and simply substitute the points to find all $a_i$. Then you can find $P(x = k+1)$ by evaluating the polynomial.

Comment: that would not be practical..

Comment: It is  practical. Just takes more work than Schrodinger's Cat's most recently edited A.(at 10:10 a.m.EDT).